# Handling network errors in Kotlin flows - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create an offline-first app in Jetpack Compose. I created a repository that exposes a flow with local data - getCurrenciesStream() and a function that makes an API call to refresh the currencies - currenciesRepository.refreshCurrencies(), which updates the local data with the fetched one. But how do I handle errors that the network request could potentially cause? I want to set the currenciesUiState to CurrenciesUiState.Error if the refreshCurrencies() call in .map { } fails.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class CurrenciesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val currenciesRepository: CurrenciesRepository,
): ViewModel() {
    val currenciesUiState = currenciesRepository.getCurrenciesStream()
        .map { currencies ->
            if (currencies.isNotEmpty()) {
                return@map CurrenciesUiState.Success(currencies)
            }
            refreshCurrencies()
            CurrenciesUiState.Loading
        }
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L),
            initialValue = CurrenciesUiState.Loading,
        )

    fun refreshCurrencies() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            currenciesRepository.refreshCurrencies()
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried doing it like this:

```
try {
    refreshCurrencies()
    CurrenciesUiState.Loading
} catch (e: IOException) {
    CurrenciesUiState.Error
}
```

but since refreshCurrencies() launches a coroutine and returns the control immediately the error won't be caught. Another option is to put a try-catch in the refreshCurrencies() function itself, but then I can't update the state right? Am I missing something? I know that the task can easily be done the MutableStateFlow way, but I wonder if I can do this with my approach.